# Append dictionary to a csv file and back to dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to append dictionary to csv file and then back to dictionary. I don't want to write it just to append it.

```
from tkinter import *
import csv
dictionary = {"Alex" : 5, "Ben": 10}
with open("dict.csv", "a") as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  for key, value in dictionary.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
with open("dict.csv") as csv_file:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  dictionary = dict(reader)

print(dictionary)
```

I want to have output {"Alex" : 5, "Ben": 10} and it will get me ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 0; 2 is required. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Is it necessary to use `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`, the actual way to work with csv file as dictionary is that to use `csv.DictWriter` and `csv.DictReader` if you are interested, I answered that ...

Answer (score 1):

### Why `ValueError`?

because when you trying to turn the reader to a dict using `dict(reader)`
dict actually needs a sequence of tuples (actually any kind of iterator with length two) but the reader is a sequence of sequence, so dict Complains that the first element of reader sequence is a sequence with zero elements on it ...

### What can I do

writing part of your solution is ok (but it can improve with [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter))
the real problem is when you want to read it...

```py
from tkinter import *
import csv
dictionary = {"Alex" : 5, "Ben": 10}
with open("dict.csv", "a") as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  for key, value in dictionary.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
with open("dict.csv") as csv_file:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  
  dictionary = {}
  for row in reader:
    if row:
      dictionary.update({row[0]: row[1]})
  
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: That does not produce a single dict, `dictionary` is just a `DictReader`, which is an iterator over rows of dicts. You need to show OP how to read back multiple rows and join them into a single dict, 'cause that's what their write code does (going the opposite way): it splits a dict up into key-value pairs, and writes one key-value pair _per row_.

Comment: @ZachYoung thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

In your "write phase", you're *splitting* your dict up into key-value pairs, and writing one key-value pair per row:

```py
dictionary = {"Alex": 5, "Ben": 10}
with open("dict.csv", "a") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

`{"Alex" : 5, "Ben": 10}` is written to **dict.csv** like:

```
Alex,5
Ben,10
```

So, in your "read phase", you need to do the opposite and *join* rows of key-value pairs into a single dict:

```py
new_dictionary = {}
with open("dict.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        value = row[1]
        new_dictionary[key] = value

print(dictionary)
print(new_dictionary)
```

```py
{'Alex': 5, 'Ben': 10}
{'Alex': '5', 'Ben': '10'}
```

But, the ints are read as strings, so you'll need to convert those yourself:

```py
        ...
        value = int(row[1])
        ...
```

And now the new dict equals the old dict:

```py
{'Alex': 5, 'Ben': 10}
{'Alex': 5, 'Ben': 10}
```

In general for reading/writing CSV with the **csv** module, it's better to open your files with `newline=''`:

```py
with open('dict.csv', 'a', newline='') as ...
```

this tells the opener not to interpret and "fix" inconsistent newlines—which is probably good for regular text, but can be unwanted when reading a CSV file.  The CSV module's readers and writers have special knowledge/handling of newlines that are specific to CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you had is that when you are looping through the dictionary items you are adding them as a list while you are loading them you are trying to convert the list into a dict which a list can not do as they don't have key value pairs.

Here is one way to fix it:

```
import csv

data_dictonary = {"Alex" : 5, "Ben": 10}
# append to file
with open("dict.csv", "a") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in data_dictionary.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])

# read file and check contents
with open("dict.csv") as csv_file:
  dictionary = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

print(dictionary)
```

[source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-save-a-Python-Dictionary-to-CSV-file)

Comment: unfortunately, you can't turn reader object to dict simply by using `dict` on it ...